# php get values after decimal

Tags: php, floating-point, rounding

If I've got a value in a variable eg 10.2333 and I need to use the 23 of the .2333 how do i do that?  For more information, I am working out a time difference:

```
$started = $_SESSION['now'];
$ended = time();
$time1 = $ended - $started;
$time2 = $time1 / 60;
```

$time2 gives me for example 10.233

Comment: Do you need to round the remaining places off, or just truncate them away?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should give you what you want.

```
$time3 = (int)($time2 * 100) % 100;
```

Edit: Question turned out to be different. To get minutes and seconds of a unix timestamp, you should do the following.

```
$minutes = ($time1 / 60) % 60;
$seconds = $time1 % 60;
```

Comment: I've been trying this one out, not quite working, for example:
$started = 1321018907;
$ended = 1321020026;
$time1 = $ended - $started;
$time2 = $time1 / 60;
$time3 = (int)($time2 * 100) % 100; gives me:  19minutes & 64 seconds, the secons is wrong.

Comment: you may asked the question wrong. this code gives you the first two digits of the fraction part. if you want to get seconds of a unix timestamp, you should try $minutes = ($time1 / 60) % 60 and $seconds = $time1 % 60

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php
   list($before_dot, $after_dot) = explode('.', $time2);
   $result = substr($after_dot, 0, 2);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work:

```
round(($time2 - (int)$time2) , 2);
```